# Write a function that lists numbers from n to m by k number of steps. If the step size is negative list them in descending order

Tags: haskell, intervals

> Implement the `interval2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]` function,that lists numbers from the first parameter to the third parameter, the stepping's size is the second parameter. Using `[n..m]`, `[n,k..m]` or `[n..]` is prohibited.
>
> For example:

```
interval2 1 1 10 == [1,2..10]
interval2 10 1 0 == [10,11..0]
interval2 10 (-1) 0 == [10,9..0]
interval2 1 2 10 == [1,3..10]
interval2 10 2 0 == [10,12..0]
interval2 0 (-2) (-10) == [0,(-2)..(-10)]
interval2 1 (-1) 10 == [1,0..10]
interval2 0 (-10) (-1000) == [0,(-10)..(-1000)]
```

So far, I've managed to write some cases, but they didn't do the job very well.

```
interval2 x y z | x < z && y > 0 = [x] ++ interval2 (x+y) y z
                | x < z && y < 0 = [x] ++ interval2 (x-y) y z
                | x > z && y > 0 = [x] ++ interval2 (x-y) y z
                | x > z && y < 0 = [x] ++ interval2 (x+y) y z
                | x == z || x > z = [z]
```

Comment: If `y < 0`, then `x - y` will be larger than `x`.

Comment: I am struggling to understand "I've managed to write some cases, but I don't know how to write separate cases for separate cases yet"

Comment: @pedrofurla Edited that part out. What I wanted to say is that I don't know if it's possible in Haskell to do, let's say "if this condition is met, then check these next two conditions and do the one case that meets the conditions out of those two (so if `x < z`, then check if `y > 0`, if it's not, then do the remaining `y < 0` case).". Essentially I wanted to know if "nested if statements" are possible in Haskell and it turns out that I had to approach this problem in another way.

Comment: Many of your test cases look wrong. #2 and #7 should be empty (or an error), #5 should be `[10,8..0]`, and #4 should probably be `[1,3,5,7,9]`, since the trivial implementation using the `Enum` instance would be `[x,x+y..z]`.

Comment: "if this condition is met, then check these next two conditions" this is what "&&" is. If the left side && holds check the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming is important. When learning, naming is *very* important.

What is `x`? What is `y`? What is `z`? Are all of them the same, conceptually?

No, as the exercise describes it, it is

```
interval2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
interval2 from stepSize to =
```

this already gets you half way there towards the solution. Yes it does.

Or actually, you have a contradiction. According to the title of your post, it is

```
interval2b :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
interval2b from numSteps to =
```

But in any case, solving the first one first, you seem to get lost in the multitude of tests. Instead of doing all of them in one function, why not do a test to decide *which* of several functions to use to do the job; then write each of those functions being already able to assume certain things, namely those which we've tested for:

```
interval2 from stepSize to 
   | stepSize > 0 = increasing from 
   | stepSize < 0 = decreasing from 
   | otherwise    = []
  where
  increasing from 
    | from
```

and now it is easy to see which test to perform here, isn't it?

```
            > to = []
    | otherwise  = from : increasing ....
  decreasing from
    | from
```

and similarly here.

```
              .........
     ..................
```

I hope this helps you manage this complexity so you'll be able to complete this code yourself.

Answer (score 4):

There are basically two cases when you should emit a new value:

1. if `x <= z` and `y > 0`; and
2. if `x >= z` and `y < 0`.

In both cases that means the list contains `x` as first element and should recurse on the interval with `x+y`. In case none of these conditions are not met, then we have reached the end of the list.

This thus means that the function looks like:

```
interval2 x y z
    | (x <= z && y > 0) || (x >= z && y < 0) = …
    | otherwise = …
```

where I leave implementing `…` as an exercise.